# injecting generics with roboguice

Tags: java, guice

I'm trying to inject instances with generics and i'm getting the following error:

```
HasOne<ModelClass> cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.
```

I've read elsewhere that safest way to do this is to explicitly name the class to be used in the generic when using the injector to get an instance but i'd like to be a little cleaner. I'm trying to create `Relationship` objects between `Models`.

Here is my simplified `Model` class

```
public class Model {

    @Inject
    Injector injector;

    public <ModelClass extends Model> HasOne<ModelClass> hasOne(Class<ModelClass> clazz) {

        HasOne<ModelClass> hasOne = injector.getInstance(Key.get(new TypeLiteral<HasOne<ModelClass>>() {
        }));

        hasOne.init(clazz);

        return hasOne;
    }
}
```

My `HasOne` relationship

```
public class HasOne<T extends Model> {

    Class clazz;

    public void init(Class<T> clazz){
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @Inject
    Injector injector;

    public T get(){

        return (T) injector.getInstance(clazz);
    }
}
```

Test `Model` #1

```
public class TestModel extends Model {

    public HasOne<ExampleModel> exampleModel(){

        return hasOne(ExampleModel.class);
    }
}
```

Test `Model` #2

```
public class ExampleModel extends Model {
}
```

I get the error when doing this

```
    TestModel testModel = RoboGuice.getInjector(context).getInstance(TestModel.class);

    HasOne<ExampleModel> relationship = testModel.exampleModel();
```

I'm trying to hide away the ugly relationship creation and keep it in the `Model` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `new TypeLiteral<T>() { }` if `T` is a type parameter, it has to be a fully-specified type.  Luckily, since you have an instance of `Class<ModelClass>`, you can do this:

```
(Key<HasOne<ModelClass>>) Key.get(TypeLiteral.get(Types.newParameterizedType(HasOne.class, clazz)))
```

You'll get a warning on the cast but it is safe to suppress it.

Comment: +1000. Magnificent response, I've been searching for this solution to my problem I do not know what time. I was almost to the point of implementing an adaptation of Autofac to Android.