# guice: automate binding of generic classes

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Is it possible to automate bindings of generic classes?
Consider this:

**Generic interface:**

```
public interface IAction<T> {
     T echo(T inst);
}
```

**Long subtype:**

```
public class LongAction implements IAction<Long> {    
    @Override
    public Long echo(Long inst) {return inst;}
}
```

**String subtype:**

```
public class StringAction implements IAction<String> {
    @Override
    public String echo(String inst) {return inst;}
}
```

**Custom module:**
public class CustomModule extends AbstractModule {

```
@Override
protected void configure() {
  //do this automagically?
  bind(new TypeLiteral<IAction<String>>() {}).to(StringAction.class);
  bind(new TypeLiteral<IAction<Long>>() {}).to(LongAction.class);
  //
}
```

}

**Main**

```
// i know i can obtain the correct instance
IAction<String> is = injector.getInstance(new Key<IAction<String>>(){});
```

Is it possible to auto bind, in some way(eg: base abstract class, reflection or whatever) the binding of the `StringAction` and `LongAction` classes? I've tried using reflection to no avail.

Comment: How do you want to automatically discover `LongAction`, `StringAction`, etc?  Are they in a particular package or something?  What if two classes implement `IAction<String>`?

Comment: @TavianBarnes they are in a particular package. I don't mind assuming there's no two impls for the same `T` for now, so there won't be two `IAction<String>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow managed to trick the compiler.

```
class CustomModule extends AbstractModule {

static class Holder<T> {
    Class<T> param;
    Class<IAction<T>> klass;

    Holder(Class<?> p, Class<IAction<T>> k) {
        param = (Class<T>) p;
        klass = k;
    }
}

// this would be similar to the result of classpath scanning
List<IAction<?>> stuff;

public <T> void bindSome(Class<T> typeParameter, Class<IAction<T>> implementation) {
    Type parameterizedType = Types.newParameterizedType(IAction.class, typeParameter);
    bind((TypeLiteral<IAction<T>>) TypeLiteral.get(parameterizedType)).to(implementation);
}

public CustomModule() {
    stuff = new ArrayList<>();
    stuff.add(new StringAction());
    stuff.add(new LongAction());
}

@Override
protected void configure() {
    for (IAction<?> act : stuff) {
        System.out.printf("Configuring %s for %s\n", act.getTypeArguments(), act.getClass());
        //the following doesn't work because the compiler cannot understand that 
        //the 1st argument T is the same T in 2nd argument Class<T>
        //bindSome(act.getTypeArguments(), act.getClass());

        //w00t? compiler is tricked?? <String> is erased, but the holder preserves proper class?
        Holder<String> holder = new Holder(act.getTypeArguments(), (Class<IAction<String>>) act.getClass());
        bindSome(holder.param, holder.klass);

        //this is what I want to avoid doing manually
        //bind(new TypeLiteral<IAction<String>>() {}).to(StringAction.class);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do some sort of classpath scanning if you don't want to explicitly list the implementations.  Guava has some support with its [ClassPath](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/ClassPath.html) class, for example.

Note that classpath scanning is somewhat antithetical to the design philosophy of Guice.  Is it really so much extra effort to add one line to a module for every implementation you write?

Comment: The problem is not with classpath scanning. The problem is with the generic type.

Comment: Ah I didn't realise.  You figured out the solution already but I've given it before, for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17617369/502399

Comment: Thanks, I googled for it but didn't find your answer.